# Finding a pattern in sum of products of two or more variables with subscripts

Tags: pattern-matching, operators

I am trying (so far unsuccessfully) to isolate terms in an expression which are product of variables with a specific subscript pattern (the b_,_'s). I want only terms for which the first subscript index is different in all b's that appear in a product. e.g. for $b_{1,2} b_{2,1} r_{1,2,2,1}$ the first subscript of the first b is 1 and the first subscript of the second b is 2, so this is a valid term. $b_{1,2} b_{1,1} r_{1,1,2,2}$ would not be valid as the first indices of both b's are identical.

I have tried to use patterns

Expression = $b_{1,1}^2 r_{1,1,2,1} r_{2,1,2,1}+b_{1,2} b_{1,1} r_{1,1,2,2} r_{2,1,2,1} +b_{1,2} b_{2,1} r_{1,2,2,1} r_{2,1,2,2}$

But I already fail to specify a pattern on a product of b's... This works: (It will isolate all terms that contain a b where the second index is 1

```
Select[Expression, MemberQ[#, Subscript[b_, _, 1]] &]
```

This however does not:

```
Select[Expression, MemberQ[#, Subscript[b_, 1, _]]*Subscript[b_, 1, 1]] &]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(expr 
   /. (Subscript[b, x_, y_] -> btmp[x] Subscript[b, x, y]) )
   /. {btmp[x_]^y_ /; y > 1 -> 0, btmp[x_] -> 1}
```

This double replacement collects all of the first indices in a temporary multiplier. If any first index appears multiple times, it forms a power which is then replaced with 0. Otherwise, all of the multipliers are re-replaced with 1 again and vanish.

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely!